# xst terminal: normal clipboard disabled when in tmux

Tags: tmux, clipboard, suckless-terminal

When use xst not in tmux, clipboard somehow share the same with the system/os/or-whatever-idk, but I can copy from `firefox/chrome` and paste into xst.

But with tmux I can't do that, tmux only allow use its own buffer, how to make tmux use the `system buffer` that share with other program?

Answer (score 0):

If you use linux you cloud add:

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

If on OSX use:

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
```

Taken from [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tmux-in-practice-integration-with-system-clipboard-bcd72c62ff7b/)

Answer (score -1):

tmux needs help from `xsel` (or another X clipboard manager).

I use `xsel` and add this to my `~/.tmux.conf`, which will allow CTRL+B CTRL+C (copy) and CTRL+B CTRL+X (paste) to/from the X (PRIMARY) clipboard into the tmux selection buffer (and vice versa).

```
# turn on clipboard
set -g set-clipboard on

# copy tmux's selection buffer into the X clipboard selection
bind-key C-c run-shell "tmux show-buffer | xsel -b -i" \; \
display-message "Clipboard buffer copied to xsel ..."

# copy X clipboard selection into tmux's selection buffer
bind-key C-x run-shell "xsel -b -o | tmux load-buffer -" \; \
display-message "Clipboard buffer copied from xsel ..."
```

Comment: Not quite sure but enable clipboard and all set `set -g set-clipboard on`. I can now use system buffer via pre-defined paste shortcut keyboard from system and do paste.